# how to configure atom with anaconda virtual environment interpreter

Tags: python, atom-editor, spyder, conda

I am trying to run my code in atom using a pre-defined conda venv interpreter, however, i could not open the interpreter venv in the atom terminal due to "un authorized.. security" thing, and when i tried to run the code from cmd there happens to be syntax errors. Although the same code with same interpreter were working in spyder. what could be the reason?